# Cypress Testing Drag & Drop Three.js Canvas

Tags: canvas, three.js, cypress, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I'm currently trying to get some drag and drop cypress tests working for a react three fibre project. I'm stuggling a little to test this however as I don't have selectable ID's for the 3D elements to be used in cypress as all of the three.js elements are wrapped up in the HTML canvas.

My tests start as follows:

```
cy.viewport(1920, 1080);
cy.get('[data-testid="r3f"] canvas').as('canvas');
cy.get('@canvas').click({ x: 1390, y: 320 }); <--- Pos of object to drag & drop
```

With the above snippet I'm able to select object in the scene and enable the transform controls as follows:

[image]

I then want to select the yellow drag square and move the objects position for my test.

I've tried both using [cypress trigger](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/trigger) & [cypress-real-events](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events) & a combination of the two with no sucsess

```
  cy.get('@canvas')
    .realMouseMove(1390, 340)
    .realMouseDown(1390, 340) <--- Mousedown not able to take take X/Y as params
    .realMouseMove(1100, 300)
    .realMouseUp({ force: true });
```

Using the above cypress-real-events seems to have got me closest to what I need, in the test replay realMouseMove is placing the mouse over the drag box, as follows:

[image]

However .realMouseDown(1390, 340) doesn't have the option of passing X&Y instead it defaults to the topLeft the selected element, so in my case the canvas @ 0,0. This then results in the orbit controls of the scene being triggered on the second realMouseMove rotating the scene and no drag and drop being perfomed. realMouseEnd working as expected :)

```
  cy.get('@canvas')
    .trigger('mousemove', { clientX: 1394, clientY: 320, force: true })
    .trigger('mousedown', { clientX: 1394, clientY: 320, force: true, button: 0 })
    .trigger('mousemove', { clientX: 1100, clientY: 300, force: true })
    .trigger('mouseup');
```

Using the above cypress trigger method seems to be working less. mousemove doesn't show the active hover state over the transform controls as with realEvents.

Any help with this would be much appreciated. Feel like I'm getting nowhere with this

Comment: Do you have any way, method, etc. that you can find out the positions of each element on the canvas? This can be provided to you by the developers of the same canvas. They must have it stored and can provide you with a function that is exposed to the `window` browser object, and you can get the info then before executing a test.

If the above is not possible for any reason, can you maybe achieve the state of this canvas to be predictable and pre-defined and always the same before the test run? The canvas all objects inside of it?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Darko, I'm passing in test data to the scene so the state of the canvas will always be predictable... its more an issue of being able to interact with the three.js (react-three-fibre) transform contols within the canvas via cypress

Comment: No problem. I will try out something this day or two and provide you with a working example. On my Canvas project I did create a nice framework using mouse events, but still have to test it with a three.js project.

Answer (score 3):

The `cypress-real-events` documentation needs some updating.

If you take a look here [mouseDown.ts](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events/blob/672df4f11107059f55477ade01f368d854776bfc/src/commands/mouseDown.ts#L37) you can see that the coordinates are passed in as an object like this: `{ x:123, y:456 }` (relative to the `<canvas>` not the screen).

**Type definition for mouseDown options**

```js
export interface realMouseDownOptions {
  ...
  cy.get("canvas").realMouseDown({ x: 100, y: 115 })
```

**Implementation**

```js
const position =
    options.x && options.y ? { x: options.x, y: options.y } : options.position;

const { x, y } = getCypressElementCoordinates(
  subject,
  position,
  options.scrollBehavior,
);
...
await fireCdpCommand("Input.dispatchMouseEvent", {
  type: "mousePressed",
  x,
  y,
```